# Hashmap get(key) returns null even when the value is present

Tags: java, android, null, hashmap

I'm trying to save datas in a hash map and retrieve it. The value corresponding to the key is present and it still returns null. I have implemented the equals() and hashCode() methods also.

```
ArrayList<Friends> friendsArrayList = new ArrayList<Friends>();
HashMap<Friends,ArrayList<FriendDetails>> friendDetailsHashMap = new HashMap<Friends, ArrayList<FriendDetails>>();
int mSelectedIndex = 0;
...
Friends f = friendsArrayList.get(mSelectedIndex);
ArrayList<MeterGroups> temp2 = friendDetailsHashMap.get(mp); //<== This is where it returns null
```

My ObjectClass Friends.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Friends implements Serializable {
private String friendName;
private String friendId;
private double distanceFromCurrentLocation;

public Friends(String name, String id)
{
    this.friendName = name;
    this.friendId = id;
    this.distanceFromCurrentLocation = getDistanceFromCurrentLocation();

}

public String getFriendName(){
    return friendName;
}

public void setFriendName(String name){
    this.friendName = name;
}

public void setFriendId(String id){
    this.friendId = id;
}
public String getFriendId(){
    return friendId;
}

public double getDistanceFromCurrentLocation(){
    return 0.0;
}

public int hashCode(){
    return friendName.hashCode()*friendId.hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if(!(o instanceof Friends)) {
        return false;
    }

    Friends other = (Friends) o;
    return this.friendId == other.friendId; //friendId is a unique value
   }
}
```

Comment: Where do you add to the `HashMap`? Is that in the "..."?

Comment: @codeMagic I get it from my intent. Some values are null and some are not. I'm first creating a hashmap with all values null and then adding the datas as I get from webservice. But the key whose value i'm trying to get is not a null

Comment: [com.fresco.mobile.app_data.Friends@ee5f8300, com.fresco.mobile.app_data.Friends@80c31c61].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your .equals method in Friends.

When comparing strings, use .equals instead of ==

So the last line should look like this:

```
return this.friendId.equals(other.friendId);
```

Comment: @Rani I's glad I could help :)

Answer (score 5):

Your `equals` implementation *only* uses `friendId`. Your `hashCode` implementation uses both `friendName` *and* `friendId`. Therefore there can be two equal objects with different hash codes.

Additionally, you're using `==` to compare strings within `equals`, instead of `equals`. That's comparing *references* rather than the textual data.

Also, you'll need to handle the possibility that `friendId` or `friendName` are `null`. (So don't just call either `equals` or `hashCode` on them unconditionally.) You may well want to use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) which has methods to help when writing both `hashCode` and `equals`.

Finally, you're using a *mutable* data type as a key in a hash map. That's generally a bad idea - if you add a key to a map and then mutate the object in a way which will affect the hash code, you'll be unable to fetch with the same key later. I would *strongly* encourage you to use immutable types as map keys.

You need to decide what your equality criteria are, and be consistent between both `hashCode` and `equals`. If those two aren't consistent, you may well see issues like this.

Comment: Thank you!! This helped.. Both your and @Anubian Noob's answer helped and I'm accepting his since he answered first. I really appreciate your help!!